# TeXstudio2015,help file, Auto Completion,The following display mode is obtained by which shortcut keys.？

Tags: texstudio

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
My computer system is win10, I try the shortcut keys as the file, but The results are not the same as the instruction。 Shiftl+Alt+Space seem has some effect.

[TeXstudio/help/usermanual_en][5]

http://file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/TeXstudio/help/usermanual_en.html#SECTION1